# Parents of Maha Vishnu

Tags: vishnu, scripture, puranas

This question was asked by my 8 year old son-- Who are the parents of Mahavishnu? He further added to put this question in stack exchange. Although I told him that Lord Vishnu manisfests himself he is the creator  presever and destroyer  he said we are born to mother. Likewise Mahavishnu also will have partents like me. Explore and tell.

Comment: MahaVishnu is called 'Aja' meaning unborn. Brahma sutra says 'janmadiyasya yatah'; meaning from whom birth etc;as in from whom everything has come into being. So Mahavishnu does not have parents like us. He is supreme. But Gaudiya vaishnavas however say that mahavishnu is secondary expansion of Krishna.But yes all Vaishnav sects agree that all Vishnu tatva are unborn; as in they are eternal :)

Answer (score 4):

It's Brahman (Not the Brahma. Brahman/Brahmam is also known as the Parabrahma)  that only exists. Vishnu, Siva, Shakti, Brahma all are just different forms of Brahman. We cannot explain or define Brahman and if we can, then it's not Brahman.

So coming to your question, it depends on which branch you follow. The origin of Mahavishnu is different on different texts.

If you go by Shiva purana, Siva created Brahma and Vishnu. Siva was in the form of a pillar , when brahma and vishnu were fighting over who is more powerful.

If you go by shrimad bhagvata, Mahavishnu manifested himself.

There is many other concepts in Hinduism like, Swayambhoo Manu, Prakruthi- Purush Samyog etc..

It's up to you what you believe and what you have to follow. You can even think deeply (like a state of meditation) and can create your own concepts. The final truth is that only Parabrahma exists ( and only it's real) and whichever path we choose/take, it will lead us to him once we realize ourseleves.

Comment: Anybody  can give a theoretical answer. You put your opinion in comment not in answer. Even I can put this in comment. I was looking for purnaical substantiation. Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.